# php to authenticate a unique user over internet so that even a remote desktop user using authentic ip can be blocked

Tags: php

I am making a login script that I would like to be as secure as possible. Problem is, security seems to be a never ending battle. So essentially, I am looking for suggestions and improvements to my ideas.
I have an application based on e token,so that only users with e token user name and password can authorize the workflow,but it is quite possible that a person can remote login and access the system.
though i tried to use authenticate user with IP but its not fool proof method.
Is there any other way by which i can make my system robust enough to avoid spoofs?
Can MAC address be captured in PHP ,if so how?

any solution are welcomed...

Comment: _I would like to be as secure as possible_ - there you troubles start. The problem should not be solved with "as secure as possible". It should be solved with "secure enough to ..." (here `...` points to business-logic and it's requirements)

Comment: MAC Address cannot be captured using PHP. However you can capture MAC Addresses of PC which is connected through your local network.

Answer (score 0):

Hate to say it, the best thing you can do, is capture their IP address, use something like https://www.php.net/gethostbyaddr and find out the area they are logging in from.  From there you can make sure the area doesn't vary too much.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to determine that a user is connected to a computer via remote desktop. The traffic is originating from the correct IP so whether or not they are physically there is impossible to determine. Think of a corporate user connected to the office via a VPN. They could be anywhere in the world but their IP will be that of the office. There is nothing you can do about that. Also, what if the user's IP changes mid session? Perhaps they may drop from WiFi to 3G data for example, or even they're behind some form of load balancing or proxy server.

Also, you can't capture the device MAC address in PHP.

I assume based on the mentions of IP addresses this is some form of web based, or even network based, application. To get going you should ensure you are using TLS. All the security in the world won't help you if you're communicating in plain text. Once TLS is up and running you should consider HSTS or at least a manual implementation of the same functionality if it's not a browser based portal.